# How style div so that it scrolls down with page - stuck to the RIGHT side of browser

Tags: html, css

I need to style a div so that it scrolls down with page AND is not stuck to the LEFT side of browser like this:

```
#flyingDIV{
position:fixed;
top:160px;
left:0px;   
}
```

instead I need it to be stuck to the RIGHT side.
thanx in advance.

Comment: Instead of `left` use `right`, like `right: 0;`?

Comment: To clarify, you want it to "scroll down with the page" or to stay in the same place when scrolling the page?

Comment: I've shared a link with you, which you can use to design awesome layout using css... I hope my answer will help you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are new to `css` , I'll recommend this tutorial link for you **http://learnlayout.com/**

This website help you learn - How to design a good layout using **CSS**

```
#flyingDIV
{
    position:fixed;
    top:160px;
    right:0px;   
}
```

To set it from bottom of your page you can use

```
bottom :20px;
```

Comment: The link http://learnlayout.com/ I've shared with you is really awesome... and is very quick, I think you can spare 5 minutes of your time for this

Comment: @Dr.Zoidberg So, what is the problem, you are facing here.... Isn't it working ???

Comment: no, it isn't working. as I posted above, it just pastes the div in the middle of the webpage. I need it to be on the right side.

Comment: In this case...I need you to write your whole code... because I need to know... what layout you are using..

Comment: I kinda figured it out. It is about where you place your div in the code. The CSS is ok with position fixed and right set to zero. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: done. thanks. looks like I can accept only one answer. pretty unjust. I appreciate all these guys that tried to help me and actually helped me.

Comment: Yes, you are right..... you can suggest this idea on Meta Stackoverflow, I appreciate it.....I can give you the link http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ where you can share your idea..... Yes you can stil appreciate other guys, by just upvoting their answers, please identify the upvote button

Answer (score 2):

```
#flyingDIV{
  position:fixed;
  top:160px;
  right:0px;   
}
```

Comment: I tried this and all it does is that it pastes the div in the middle of the page. I think it has something to do with the position of my div in my html code...any ideas? and to showdev: yes, it should be in one place even if scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried floating it?

```
#flyingDIV {
    float: right;
}
```

Whether this works or not depends on what else you have on your page surrounding the div you're trying to aligh to the right.

Comment: A fixed element doesn't float.

Comment: The question specifies that it scolls down with the page, so it shouldn't be fixed.

Comment: They're asking for it to be positioned to the right and scroll with the page... To be honest I think it's how you interpret the question... it needs to be more specific.

Comment: The OP is a bit vague in his question. But I think with "scrolls down" he means, that the element actually stays, while everything else scrolls up.

Comment: I tried this and all it does is that it pastes the div in the middle of the page. I think it has something to do with the position of my div in my html code...any ideas?